# PHP - RegExp get the last hashtags part of a tweet

Tags: php, regex, twitter

Let be a tweet posted as the following examples:

```
any #kind of @characters here #hashtag1 #stunning #hasthag2 [just punctuation here]*
any #kind of @characters here #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #stunning [just punctuation here]*
any #kind of @characters here #stunning #hashtag1 #hashtag2 [just punctuation here]*
```

I need a regural expression which returns the last part of the tweet, that is, the ending n+ hashtag, knowing that one of them (in any position) will be a known one (e.g. #stunning).

My current implementation is:

```
(.*)(((#[^\s]+)[ ]?)*(#stunning)[ ]?((#[^\s]+)[ ]?)*)([\W]*)
```

http://regex101.com/r/rX3kM1/1

PHP Code:

```
$tweet = "any #kind of @characters here #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #stunning !!?!?...";
preg_match("/(.*)(((#[^\s]+)[ ]?)*(#stunning)[ ]?((#[^\s]+)[ ]?)*)([\W]*)/", $tweet, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => any #kind of @characters here #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #stunning !!?!?...
    [1] => any #kind of @characters here #hashtag1 #hashtag2
    [2] => #stunning
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
    [5] => #stunning
    [6] =>
    [7] =>
    [8] => !!?!?...
)
```

Desidered Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => any #kind of @characters here #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #stunning !!?!?...
    [1] => any #kind of @characters here 
    [2] => #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #stunning
    ...
)
```

Comment: what are the rules? What are all possibilities?

Comment: Do you want everything since the first hashtag?

Comment: not exactly, just the final hasthags... in the first part of the tweet there might be some unrelated hashtag. e.g. any #kind of characters here or @mention I don't care #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #stunning just-punctuation-here

Comment: You should highlight it more maybe if you want a specific hastag in the list of hashtags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the following regex should do it:

```
^(.*?)((?:#\w+\W*)*(?:#stunning)\W*?(?:#\w+\W*?)*)(\W*)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/rX3kM1/5

It matches the last occurence of `#stunning` and any hashtags before and after that. Only non word charcter are allowed between them and after the last one.

The last hastags are in group 2, the text before in group 1 and the punctuation directly after the last is in group 3.

Answer (score 1):

If, to qualify, your hashtag group must both

1. Have `#stunning` in it
2. Be the last group of hashtags in the sentence (followed by anything)

You can use:

```
(?=.*#stunning)#\w+(?:\s+#\w+)*(?!.*\s#\w)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?=.*#stunning)` makes sure the mandatory hashtag is in the mix
- `#\w+` grabs a first hashtag
- `(?:\s+#\w+)*` grabs the possible hashtags *directly* following
- `(?!.*\s#\w)` makes sure there isn't any hashtag left afterwards

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uJ0bC5/5).

If you want to allow only punctation after the ending hashtag group you can replace `(?!.*\s#\w)` with `(?=\W*$)` or `(?=[\s:!;.?...]*$)` - depending on what you call "punctuation".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understood your question but if you want to get the last hashtag you can use this regex:

```
.*(#\w+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/mB8rD7/1)**

[image]

Comment: I've fixed my request, which now is much more clear (i hope...) - thank you for you time

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str  = "any kind of characters here #hashtag1 #stunning #hasthag2 !❤";
preg_match("/([a-z ]+)((#\w+ ))((#\w+ ))((#\w+ ))(!.)/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>

Output:
Array ( 
[0] => any kind of characters here #hashtag1 #stunning #hasthag2 !â
[1] => any kind of characters here 
[2] => #hashtag1 
[3] => #hashtag1 
[4] => #stunning 
[5] => #stunning 
[6] => #hasthag2 
[7] => #hasthag2 
[8] => !â 
)
```

I believe by default preg_match returns the full match as the value for the first index in the match array. So you would have to delete this index, and run array_unique on matches, and viola!

Answer (score -1):

i guess this should do it:

```
(.*?)(#.*)\s(?!#)(.*)
```